# Debug SparkSQL Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-debugger

What are some way I can debug through a sparksql query?

I have defined a dataframe with a sparpksql query and I have included show(1), but the query continues to run very long. Could anyone provide pointers? Thank you!

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.cd
where t1.product = 'I'
and not exists
(select * from table3 t3
        where t3.id = t1.id 
        and t3.year = t1.year
        and a3.month = t1.month
        and t3.day = t1.day
        and t3.code in ('4321','5604'))
and not exists
(select MAX(status) from table4 t4
        where t4.id = t1.id
        and t4.year = t1.year
        and t4.month = t1.month
        and t4.day = t1.day
        having max(status) > 3)
""").show(1)
```

list_of_id_df.createOrReplaceTempView("list_of_id")

list_of_id_df.show(1)

print("Done")

Comment: Have a look at [explain](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain.html). This might give you a hint what Spark is doing.

Comment: What you're looking for is not "debugging", but "testing" your query out. If the query itself took too long, you can try one of these approaches: 1) limit your input table by creating some temp tables 2) try with each subqueries before running the whole thing

Comment: @pltc For option 1, do you mean something like this? table1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
       database = 'database1',
       table_name = 'table1',
 additional_options={"catalogPartitionPredicate":"year='2022' and month='09' and day='15'"}) // convert dynamic frame to spark dataframe: table1_df = table1.toDF() // Create view: table1_df.createOrReplaceTempView("table1"). Then, I can query the table with spark.sql("insert query")